# How to define a function on one line

Tags: bash, function, syntax

Often when moving files around, I need to do the opposite later. So in my .bashrc I included this working code:

```
rmv() {
  mv $2/${1##*/} ${1%/*}
}
```

Now I wonder why I can't write this as a single liner. This is what I tried:

```
rmv() {mv $2/${1##*/} ${1%/*}}
```

If I do so, I get this error:

```
-bash: .bashrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `{mv'
```

Comment: Did you try giving it a token it *would* expect?

Comment: Have you defined an alias of the same name?

Comment: There is an earlier, equivalent question on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/521937/13975).

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In Bash, `{` is not automatically recognized as a special/separate token from what's around it. So you need whitespace between `{` and `mv`.

Additionally:

- `}` needs to be the start of a command; so if it's not on its own line, you need `;` to terminate the previous command.
- It's a best practice to always use double-quotes around any parameter expansion, since otherwise you'll get bizarre behaviors when the parameters include whitespace or special characters.

So:

```
rmv() { mv "$2/${1##*/}" "${1%/*}" ; }
```

Comment: why don't they fix bash so it doesn't always mess up whitespaces?

Comment: @Jason: The weird behavior with whitespace is specified by POSIX. \[[link](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05)] And, unfortunately, there are a *lot* of existing shell scripts that rely on it.

Comment: Good info with the closing brace that is the start of a command. It works with semicolon, but where did you get this info? `bash closing brace start of command` in google did not push me on the track.

Comment: @Timo: The *Bash Reference Manual* is available online: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html. The relevant section is §3.2.5.3 "Grouping Commands": https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping. It words it very differently -- my "start of command" wording isn't really the most accurate -- which is part of why your Google search didn't find it.

Comment: @Jason why don't they fix whitespaces so they don't always mess up bash? :D