# Pass command line -- argument to child script in Yarn

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I have a package.json that looks similar to this:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=client webpack --config webpack/client.development.js && yarn dev:stub-server | cross-env BABEL_ENV=server babel-node src/server/server.js",
    "dev:stub-server": "./node_modules/.bin/robohydra ./stubs/robohydra-config.json -p 3100"
}
```

I added some logic in the code to change the way the `dev:stub-server` is configured depending on a command line argument. So, whenever I run the following I get what I expect:

```
yarn dev:stub-server --results=4
$ ./node_modules/.bin/robohydra ./stubs/robohydra-config.json -p 3100 -- --results=4
```

As you can see, the options are forwarded to the underlying script and everything works as expected.

My problem is that I cannot have the `--results` propagated from the `yarn dev` command to `dev:stub-server` in the correct position. The parent script runs `dev:stub-server` but the argument is forwarded to the underlying script at the end as follows:

```
yarn dev --results=2
$ cross-env BABEL_ENV=client webpack --config webpack/client.development.js && yarn dev:stub-server | cross-env BABEL_ENV=server babel-node src/server/server.js --results=2
```

Is there a way to make the above work as follows instead?

```
yarn dev --results=2
$ cross-env BABEL_ENV=client webpack --config webpack/client.development.js && yarn dev:stub-server --results=2 | cross-env BABEL_ENV=server babel-node src/server/server.js
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Yarn's `run`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/) only supports appending your `args` to the end of the command chain, and at least as of date 2018-06-14, there isn't a way to override that.

When I've needed this in the past, I've cooked up my own `dev.js` script that was called by my `package.json`, and pulled args out environment variables.

Answer (score 54):

On mac I am using:

```
"scripts": {
  "benchmark": "sh -c 'ng run ${0}:benchmark'",
}
```

Which I then call `yarn benchmark editor` where `editor` is my parameter.

Comment: This will fail on windows, of course, unless you can tell everyone using your package that they need to install `bash` (either via cygwin or git for windows). I don't think this is reasonable for open source, but I use it all over the place for my closed-source project.

Comment: Hi, this is awesome, but can I pass the argument to somewhere inside executed script? I need something like `yarn semistandard --fix $(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~${0})`

Comment: Holy crap this saved me - thank you SO MUCH! Do you know why it starts at 0 not 1 though?

Comment: So is there a way to do this on Windows without bash?

Comment: With this, the default value will be "sh".
Any ideas to override the default value if nothing is provided?

Answer (score 27):

A straightforward way to achieve this is to write [an inline Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38595559/1470607) using [parameter expansion with  `$@`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/1470607):

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "wrap () { node index.js \"$@\" | cat; }; wrap"
}
```

Calling the above with `yarn dev foo bar` will run `node index.js foo bar` and then pipe the result into `cat` as a demo.
You can tack on commands both to the start and the end, simply keep in mind that semis are required here.

For anything more involved you'll probably want a standalone script.

Comment: @Etheryte I'm missing something very basic here. On Windows, I'm running similar inline bash function in git bash, but getting `wrap is not recognized as an internal or external command...`. Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: For anyone encountering the same issue as a YARN user. Yarn by default uses `bin\sh`, in which this particular inline Bash function cannot be run. You need to set Yarn to use `bin\bash` by executing this `yarn config set script-shell bin\bash`

Comment: For those who use this solution, `"wrap () { node index.js $* | cat; }; wrap"` try this if it doesn't work without any parameters

Comment: I would recommend using `"$@"` instead of `"$*"` or `$*`, since it'll work properly with multiple parameters, no parameters, and parameters that contain whitespace (the other variants mess some or all of these up).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks a lot for the heads up, I was not aware of the difference. I've updated the answer. For anyone else wanting to read up more about it, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/22607) for more details.

Comment: how about in windows?

Comment: @Etheryte It would be really helpful if you could re-write your answer in the style of the original question, i.e. writing out scripts:dev as it should appear with the wrap function built in.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you could use a `*.env` file and `cat` the variables out of it in your script.

```
"run":"docker build -t --build-arg VAR=`cat vars.env` -f Dockerfile .
```

for example

Comment: Args didn't work for me. I put them in files and cat-ed them and that worked. Then I found this.

Answer (score 3):

As for now, using `yarn 1.22.4` you can do `yarn exec tsc -- --help`. Appending the `--` does the trick

Comment: does it work without `exec`? It is not working for me and I'm working with `v1.22.15`.

Answer (score 1):

**Do it like these. As yarn will deliver parameters essentially.**

```
"scripts": {
  "runSomeShellScriptAlpha": "path/to/script_name.sh  $1 $2 $3", // redundant $x
  "runSomeShellScriptBeta": "path/to/script_name.sh",            // better 
}
```

```
yarn runSomeShellScriptBeta p1 p2 p3
```

**The alpha one works only on `Mac`/`Linux`, not on `Win10`. It's bad.**

**The beta one works both on `Mac`/`Linux` and `Win10`.**

Comment: This isn't working for me -- it doesn't replace `{script_name}` -- is it possible I'm missing something?

Comment: `{script_name}` means a customed file name. It is not a variable and won't be substituted by `shell`. Sorry for the brackets leading misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

use the npm ability to pass named custom arguments to command line as a proxy for your yarn commands:

```
 "scripts": {
      "yarn-cmd": "npm run npm-cmd --foo=bar",
      "npm-cmd": "echo \"foo value is $npm_config_foo\""
    }
```

run `yarn yarn-cmd`

read more: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config

Answer (score 1):

If you are using yarn 1.x, this might help you: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5207#issuecomment-690583826

Notice: it only works on shell, not windows :)

For instance I wanted to add args to standard version message(-m):

I changed it from

> ```
> "release:beta": "yarn test && standard-version --prerelease beta && git push --follow-tags",
> ```

to

> ```
> "release:beta": "f() { yarn test && standard-version --prerelease beta -m \"$@\" && git push --follow-tags; }; f",
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper function for your command, this way you can control the position of your arguments:

```
  "scripts": {
    "audit-page": "wrapper() { lighthouse $1 --chrome-flags='--headless'; }; wrapper "
  },
```

Then I can use:

```
yarn audit-page https://example.com
```

And it results in the following call:

```
$ wrapper() { lighthouse $1 --chrome-flags='--headless'; }; wrapper  https://example.com
```

Otherwise `lighthouse` complain as it expect the URL before options

Comment: @Cristik Could you elaborate on the differences behind the fact the answer you link to is newer?

Answer (score -1):

You can dissect your script in preScript, Script and postScript.

Example with a git typescript library project i have:

```
"predodeploy": "yarn build",
"dodeploy": "yarn config set version-git-message ",
"postdodeploy": "yarn version --minor && yarn config set version-git-message 'v%s'"
```

and then run

```
yarn dodeploy "my custom message"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is `v%s`? Why is `set` called twice? What happens when the command is run?

Comment: Frank, this is because yarn or npm version command has his own commit message specified by version-git-message git parameter, and by default his value is 'v%s'. This parameter 'v%s', is the version number. So when i do dodeploy  "my custom message", im setting version-git-message parameter form 'v%s'.  to "my custom message". Before that, a yarn build command is executed. and after dodeploy script is completed, postdeploy command is executed. here im only restoring default version-git-message parameter.

Answer (score -2):

I used the file workaround, but then discovered that I can append parameters to the command using `--` before the parameters.  So, with the normal command in the package.json file, then `yarn run cmd -- --param value` I got it working.

Answer (score -4):

Yarn "modern" (v2+) supports passing the arguments:

```
"scripts": {
  "args": "echo \"second $1 first $0 all $@\""
```

output:

```
$ yarn run args 1 2
second 2 first 1 all 1 2
```

Comment: This will still append the arguments to the command