# Send parameter to package.json script

Tags: javascript, bash, playwright

I have this script on package.json file:

```
"test:debug": "yarn build && playwright test --project=chromium-debug -c build && ts-node ./src/logs/generateLog.ts"
```

When I run this command: yarn test:debug -g 'myTestName'
I see in the terminal that it runs this command:

```
yarn build && playwright test --project=chromium-debug -c build && ts-node ./src/logs/generateLog.ts -g 'myTestName'
```

but I want it to run this command:

```
yarn build && playwright test --project=chromium-debug -c build -g 'myTestName' && ts-node ./src/logs/generateLog.ts
```

What should I change in my script in order to achieve that?

Comment: Does ["Pass command line -- argument to child script in Yarn"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835221/pass-command-line-argument-to-child-script-in-yarn) answer your question? I'd especially recommend rebinnaf's answer (or equivalently Etheryte's answer, but using `"$@"` instead of `"$*"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the command in `package.json` like that:

```
"test:debug": "yarn build && playwright test --project=chromium-debug -c build -g 'myTestName' && ts-node ./src/logs/generateLog.ts"
```

And then simply just run `yarn test:debug`

---

EDIT

A workaround would be to use a Makefile to achieve your desired result instead, but first make sure that `make` is installed on your device.

In your project root folder. Create a new Makefile and put this simple command in it (don’t forget to save the Makefile):

```
test:
    yarn build && playwright test --project=chromium-debug -c build -g '$(g)' && ts-node ./src/logs/generateLog.ts
```

(Notice the indentation in the second line, in your IDE you should replace the indentation of the second line to use a <kbd>TAB</kbd> instead of 4 spaces like I did here otherwise `make` will fire an error)

Now calling the command in a terminal would be like that:

```
make test g="myTestName"
```

This will let you to tweak the ”g” variable when calling the command and it will achieve the desired result.

Comment: Thanks. But I want 'myTestName' to be a parameter. 
I want to run it sometimes with yarn test:debug -g "test1" and at other times yarn test:debug -g "test2" and so on.
Is it possible?

Comment: @Alon Yes. There is a workaround, check my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I found something simpilier:
yarn build && playwright test --project=chromium-debug -c build \"$@\" && ts-node ./src/logs/generateLog.ts